# How to reset Git LFS Storage?

Tags: github, wav, git-lfs

I started to use git LFS because I worked on .wav files.
But for no reason I receive github mails saying that my account is blocked for exceeded quota with 1.5GB over 1GB.

However I want to reset this storage but I don't know how to do so.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method works FOR me :)

- Delete those repositories in GitHub.com
- Create some blank repositories to refresh your git LFS storage.
- Note: you can't reset your bandwidth by yourself. You must wait 30 days to avoid
  a problem that causes limit storage

Try this:
https://weirdbearddev.com/resources/learning/configuring-git-lfs-to-use-dropbox/
The official doc from github:  https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage#git-lfs-objects-in-your-repository